# Inequality on sum of Energy of induced graphs

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, graph-theory

If a connected graph $G$ is given, and induced subgraphs of $G$ with the vertex set $V_1 ,V_2 ,\dots, V_r$ such that $V(G)=V_1 \cup V_2 \cup \dots \cup V_r$ and for every $1 \le i < j \le r$ we have: $V_i \cap V_j = \emptyset$, Prove that the following inequality holds:

$$E(G) \ge E(V_1)+E(V_2)+\dots+E(V_r)$$
where $E(G)$ is the Energy the graph $G$.

This problem has been given to me as a research activity, and I have been trying to find related theorems on energy of a graph.
I have found beautiful theorems I failed to find a proof of the above theorem, upon finding a proof for this theorem I have came across the facts below:
$1)$ if $H$ is an induced sub graph of $G$ we have $E(G) \ge E(H)$
$2)$ interlacing  theorem which states that if $|V(G)|=n$, $|V(H)|=n-1$ and $H$ is an induced sub graph of $G$, then the following inequality holds:

$$\lambda_1 \le \mu_1 \le \lambda_2 \le \mu_2 \le \dots \le \mu_{n-1} \le \lambda_n$$

Where $\lambda_i$ and $\mu_i$ are the eigen values of $G$ and $H$ respectively.

Comment: There are numerous definitions of energies of the graph; do you mean spectral energy?

Comment: Hint: What's the relationship between the spectrum of a graph, and the spectrum of its connected components?

Comment: @BrandonduPreez I do not think there's an assumption that $V_i$ are connected components of $G$.

Comment: @ShengtongZhang, no, but induced subgraphs (or, more accurately in case some aren't connected, their components) *are* the connected components of a subgraph of $G$, and then one can use the first inequality that $E(G) \geq E(H)$.

EDIT: Hmm, nevermind, I see that some issues can arise with the subgraph not being induced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an excellent survey by Terry Tao that covers many related theorems.

https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/01/12/254a-notes-3a-eigenvalues-and-sums-of-hermitian-matrices/#more-3341.

In particular, Proposition 3 solves the problem you're working on.